# Why is this - count === 0 && (index = 0) - different than - count === 0, index = 0;?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was having trouble putting this together and someone advised me to change the code in the title if this post. the full algorithm is below, and it is to a Hackerrank problem. I struggle with finding how data indexes itself and how to connect the 'pieces' of code that I have together.

After doing what was suggested, this works for the test cases, but I still have no idea how it makes this work. Any explanation or link to where I can find the answer would be awesome. I have been teaching myself how to work through and break down problems and the problems like this and others with indexing issues (for lack of a better word) are the ones that always stump me. After seeing how to correct my mistake it seems so easy, but in the moment... well... let's just say I am glad i already lost my hair before starting this.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds-revisited/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&isFullScreen=false

```
let c = [1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]; //array of clouds
let e = 100; //energy, one unit is used to jump from cloud to cloud
let k = 3; //size of jump or c[(i+k)%n]
let n = c.length;
//if it lands on thundercloud, energy decreases by 2 additional units
//game ends when player is back on cloud zero c[0]

const jumpingOnClouds = () => {
    let count = 0;
    let index;
    while (index !== 0 && e >= 0) {
      count === 0, index = 0;
      index = (index + k) % n;
      console.log(index)
      e = c[index] > 0 ? e - 3 : e - 1;
      count++;
    }
  
    return e;
};

console.log(jumpingOnClouds());
```

I tried using a for loop and if statements but I could never get the loop to iterate back to the beginning and keep the i+=3 when it needed to start over at the beginning of the array.

Comment: What are you expecting `count === 0` to do? It actually does nothing other evaluates the code and does nothing with it. Do you know what a comma operator does? Do you know what && does? MDN is your friend to research it.

Comment: In reference to that line, don't try to put too many things on one line. Line breaks are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

`count === 0 && (index = 0)`

☝️ If `count` is strictly equal to `0`, assign `0` to `index` and evaluate to `0`; otherwise, evaluate to `false`.

`count === 0, index = 0`

☝️ Evaluate whether `count` is strictly equal to  `0` and discard the result; then assign `0` to `index` and evaluate to `0`.

Comment: Thank you. This is the explanation I needed. It can be hard to find this information even with MDN because MDN does not have every use case or I do not understand enough to put the individual pieces together from their explanation.